# Nom 7 doesn't backtrack when `alt` branch fails to parse

Tags: parsing, rust, nom

I am encountering some odd behavior in Nom 7 that I don't understand. I was under the impression that a failed parse in a branch of [`alt`](https://docs.rs/nom/latest/nom/branch/fn.alt.html) would backtrack and try the next branch of the `alt`, but this seems not to be the case.

In my case, I am trying to parse text of the form `{stuff between braces}`, where if the `stuff` is a valid identifier (alphanumerics and underscores), I return `Ok(Good(stuff))`, if it's not a valid identifier I return `Ok(Bad(stuff))`, and if the text isn't a bunch of stuff between curly braces than a `nom::Err` is returned.

```rust
use nom::{
    branch::alt,
    bytes::complete::is_not,
    character::complete::{char, multispace0, satisfy},
    combinator::{map, opt, recognize},
    multi::many0_count,
    sequence::{delimited, pair},
    IResult,
};

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Res<'a> {
    Good(&'a str),
    Bad(&'a str),
}

fn ident(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, &str> {
    recognize(pair(
        satisfy(|c| c.is_alphabetic() || c == '_'),
        many0_count(satisfy(|c| c.is_alphanumeric() || c == '_')),
    ))(input)
}

fn brace_expr(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, Res<'_>> {
    delimited(
        char('{'),
        alt((
            // Try to parse an identifier optionally surrounded by whitespace
            delimited(multispace0, map(ident, Res::Good), multispace0),
            // Otherwise, just take everything between the braces
            map(opt(is_not("}")), |s| Res::Bad(s.unwrap_or_default())),
        )),
        char('}'),
    )(input)
}

fn main() {
    println!("1. {:?}", brace_expr("{}"));
    println!("2. {:?}", brace_expr("{a}"));
    println!("3. {:?}", brace_expr("{ a }"));
    println!("4. {:?}", brace_expr("{?a}"));
    println!("5. {:?}", brace_expr("{ ?a }"));
    println!("6. {:?}", brace_expr("{a?}"));
    println!("7. {:?}", brace_expr("{ a? }"));
}
```

Output

```
1. Ok(("", Bad("")))
2. Ok(("", Good("a")))
3. Ok(("", Good("a")))
4. Ok(("", Bad("?a")))
5. Ok(("", Bad(" ?a ")))
6. Err(Error(Error { input: "?}", code: Char }))
7. Err(Error(Error { input: "? }", code: Char }))
```

I understand 1-5. They attempted to parse `delimited(multispace0, map(ident, Res::Good), multispace0)`, and either succeeded (#2, #3), or failed (#1, #4, #5) and moved onto the second branch of the `alt`, but in either case the `alt` succeeds and we get an `Ok`.

But I do not understand #6 and #7. When the first branch of the `alt` fails, instead of moving onto the second, they fail outright, resulting in an `Err`. Doesn't this contradict the fact that `alt` is supposed to try the next branch in the case of failure?

The only thing that seems different about #6 and #7 is that they succeed at parsing some `ident` before failing, whereas the `Ok(Bad)` ones never succeed at parsing an `ident`. But that shouldn't affect whether `alt` tries the next branch, should it?

EDIT:

If I “un-factor-out” the `char`s, then it works:

```rust
fn brace_expr2(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, Res<'_>> {
    alt((
        delimited(
            char('{'),
            delimited(multispace0, map(ident, Res::Good), multispace0),
            char('}'),
        ),
        delimited(
            char('{'),
            map(opt(is_not("}")), |s| Res::Bad(s.unwrap_or_default())),
            char('}'),
        ),
    ))(input)
}

fn main() {
    println!("1. {:?}", brace_expr2("{}"));
    println!("2. {:?}", brace_expr2("{a}"));
    println!("3. {:?}", brace_expr2("{ a }"));
    println!("4. {:?}", brace_expr2("{?a}"));
    println!("5. {:?}", brace_expr2("{ ?a }"));
    println!("6. {:?}", brace_expr2("{a?}"));
    println!("7. {:?}", brace_expr2("{ a? }"));
}
```

```
1. Ok(("", Bad("")))
2. Ok(("", Good("a")))
3. Ok(("", Good("a")))
4. Ok(("", Bad("?a")))
5. Ok(("", Bad(" ?a ")))
6. Ok(("", Bad("a?")))
7. Ok(("", Bad(" a? ")))
```

I still don't understand why `alt` doesn't work in the first case, but does in the second case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a fun one!

Your first alt-arm eats up, for example 6 and 7 "a" resp " a" and not, then expects the character "}". But it finds "?" resp "? ".

The second alt-arm is never reached in 6 and 7.

To solve this, in the manner you provided your solution, you need to throw an error when *ident* encounters anything to it's disliking.
I guess peek() is an order to see if "}" comes a long, meaning it's really good.

But, IMHO, I thin take_while might be better fit.

Comment: Oh, I see. `alt` has already succeeded by the time the parser is looking for a `}` — it can't go back in time and pick a different arm in order to make the `delimited` succeed.